# Suggestion for coloring the brackets

Tags: front-end, color, customization

In debugging my own codes, I spend countless time, not to mention degrees of frustrations, in attempts to find the ill-balance of the brackets, both the square and the curly ones. Is there a way that I can designate, always for me for example, that the double square brackets around simple variables be grey, the square brackets for enclosing logic operations, for example, If, For, Do, etc. be blue, and the curly brackets for enclosing list indices be red. This will make possible easy spotting of errors, and prevent more grey hairs for growing.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at _Preferences > Appearance > Syntax Coloring > Errors and Warnings_.